# how to get listview strings in plaintext in onclick

Tags: android, email, listview

So i have a expandablelistadapter in which if user clicks on the listitem inside expandablelist it shows up the text but i want the user's clicked item to be saved in a plain text and have a button(FINISH)where if the user clicks finish it send the plain text(listitem) that user has selected through email to a particular mail address only ..HERE is the code what can i add to do soo

//CREATE AND BIND TO ADAPTER

```
    CustomAdapter adapter=new CustomAdapter(restroActivity.this, team);
    elv.setAdapter(adapter);
    //SET ONCLICK LISTENER
    elv.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPos,
                                    int childPos, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), team.get(groupPos).players.get(childPos), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
```